# update JSON value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I'm having a problem with updating json value.
This is how I wan't to do it (`results.rows.item(0)` - SQLite query result, 1 row only):

```
data[tableName]=[results.rows.item(0)];

var signatureArray=data[tableName][0].signature.match(/.{1,6000}/g);

data[tableName][0].signature = '';
```

This is what I get then from `console.debug(data)`:

```
Object {registers: Array[1]}
    registers: Array[1]
        0: Object
            comments: "asd adas dasa"
            id: 2
            modules: "1, 0"
            passfail: 1
            present: 1
            signature: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAr8AAADICAYAAADhoYm+AAAYRElEQ..."
```

I'm using `tableName` because this is dynamic value. I'm taking values from many tables.

I want to remove signature value/set to `''`, because I need to send this data to remove server using ajax, jsonp, and with signature url is too long (414 error). I can't use `POST`.

also when i do this:

```
var signatureArray=data[tableName][0].signature.match(/.{1,6000}/g);
```

`signatureArray` is array containing 2 elements, so I get access to this value, but I can't change it.

How do I change `data[tableName][0].signature`???

Comment: *"This is how I wan't to do it:"* Why not? That's exactly how you update it, assuming that `data[tableName]` is the array in which the object with the `signature` property is found. BTW, this has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON, you're just updating the value of a property in a JavaScript object in an array.

Comment: `data[tableName][0].signature = "";` - this doesn't work, don't know why :/ And yes, `data[tableName]` is table which contains object.

Comment: @ miszczu: You'll have to show more context. That's how you update a property on an object.

Comment: Maybe 0 is not and index?
try to put "0" as string.
data[tableName]["0"].signature = "";

Comment: updated, 100% sure 0 is correct index